# Yolov8 Custom Object detection not grabbing proper values

Tags: python, yolo

From what I can tell when I use coco128.yaml I can pretty much get the values out. So I tried using labelImg and got a text file with each image from(root/train/images) inside a (root/train/labels).

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model 
# Use the model
results=model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=1)
```

config.xml

```
path: /home/arundeep/Desktop/GunzBossImageDetection/datasets
train: train/images
val: valid/images

# Classes
nc: 1

names: ["gkk"]
```

Traceback:

```
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs

Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.131  Python-3.10.6 torch-2.0.1+cu117 CPU
yolo/engine/trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8n.yaml, data=config.yaml, epochs=1, patience=50, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=None, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, show=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, vid_stride=1, line_width=None, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, boxes=True, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, cfg=None, v5loader=False, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs/detect/train15
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=1

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    751507  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [1, [64, 128, 256]]           
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3011043 parameters, 3011027 gradients, 8.2 GFLOPs

train: Scanning /home/arundeep/Desktop/GunzBossIm
val: Scanning /home/arundeep/Desktop/GunzBossImag
Plotting labels to runs/detect/train15/labels.jpg... 
/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py:118: UserWarning: The figure layout has changed to tight
  self._figure.tight_layout(*args, **kwargs)
len() of unsized object
optimizer: AdamW(lr=0.002, momentum=0.9) with parameter groups 57 weight(decay=0.0), 64 weight(decay=0.0005), 63 bias(decay=0.0)
Image sizes 640 train, 640 val
Using 0 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs/detect/train15
Starting training for 1 epochs...

      Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
  0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arundeep/Desktop/GunzBossImageDetection/imageDetection.py", line 8, in <module>
    results=model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=1)  # train the model
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/engine/model.py", line 373, in train
    self.trainer.train()
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/engine/trainer.py", line 192, in train
    self._do_train(world_size)
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/engine/trainer.py", line 315, in _do_train
    for i, batch in pbar:
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1178, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/build.py", line 38, in __iter__
    yield next(self.iterator)
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 633, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 677, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/base.py", line 239, in __getitem__
    return self.transforms(self.get_image_and_label(index))
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/augment.py", line 56, in __call__
    data = t(data)
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/augment.py", line 56, in __call__
    data = t(data)
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/augment.py", line 91, in __call__
    indexes = self.get_indexes()
  File "/home/arundeep/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/augment.py", line 144, in get_indexes
    return random.choices(list(self.dataset.buffer), k=self.n - 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/random.py", line 519, in choices
    return [population[floor(random() * n)] for i in _repeat(None, k)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/random.py", line 519, in <listcomp>
    return [population[floor(random() * n)] for i in _repeat(None, k)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```